# Using Primitive Data Types in another Class and the res/menu/.xml file

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, global-variables

I'm a very new to Java. I thought I was doing okay but have now hit a brick wall, so to speak.

The idea is I use the 'home button' '_menu' for the user to choose one of 26 formats. The format they choose has 3 variables. Those 3 variables are then used in the first xml view, along with 2 user inputs to calulate another variable. This variable is then used in a second xml view, along with a third user input here, to calculate the final answer.

I have created the 26 choices and if for example I choose option 5, on the emulator screen I see all the correct values associated with this choice. I don't think those values are getting stored anywhere. I say this because if I come out of that view and return back into it, it's not showing, as in my example, choice 5. It's showing its initial state, as though I was going into it the first time. I assume it's something to do with launching this activity from the start but is there anyway around this. Or really where do I start.

My second question is with the integer variables that I created from this choice. I need to pass them into another java file for the first set of calculations. I've tried to pass the variables/data with the, 'new intent putExtra' but can't get it to work. But I don't think I can use this anyway since the I don't want to launch the second view directly from the res/menu/ .xml view.

Not sure if this is making sense to anyone. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your first question, but it sounds like you're launching a new activity and when you quit and come back to it, everything is reset. If you're launching a new activity after selecting the options from your phone's menu button, you should implement a method that saves data to the shared preferences of the main activity. This method should be called on the activities onPause(), onDestroyed(), or onStop() method. You can also add a method on onResume() where the activity checks if there's any data stored in shared preferences and if so, make the desired changes.

[image: activity life cycle]

As for your second question...I kinda don't understand it either. new intent and putextra is used when you're starting a new activity and want to pass data to it. Views are not "launched" they are only inflated and brought on display whenever you want. I did an app once where I had everything in one activity and just using setContentView() method all the time. In the long run, it just complicated everything. It is easier to keep things simple and launch activities. Here is an example of some variables being passed to a new activity:
On my main activity (FirstActivity) I have:
(when  newActivityButton is clicked)

```
case R.id.newActivityButton:
            Intent mIntent = new     Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        String[] luckyNumbers = {
                luckyNumber[0].getText().toString(),
                luckyNumber[1].getText().toString(),
                luckyNumber[2].getText().toString(),
                luckyNumber[3].getText().toString(),
                luckyNumber[4].getText().toString(),
                luckyNumber[5].getText().toString()};
        mIntent.putExtra("luckyNumbers", luckyNumbers);
        mIntent.putExtra("message", messageField.getText().toString());
        FirstActivity.this.startActivity(mIntent);
        break;
```

luckyNumbers[] is an array of textviews.

Then on my NewActivity onCreate(), I have:

```
message = getIntent().getExtras().getString("message");
Log.i("TAG", message);
luckyNumbers = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("luckyNumbers");
cv.setLuckyNumbers(this.luckyNumbers);
cv.setMessage(this.message);
```

where cv is just a custom view I created with its own methods